# $\alpha \int_{0}^T \text{Sin}(fi−fk+Δf)∗t) \, dt$ — Why is it not giving wrong answer?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

$$\alpha \int_{0}^T \text{Sin}(fi−fk+Δf)∗t) \, dt $$

I am integrating this in Mathematica,

[image]

My code is

```
(1/2)*α*Integrate[Sin[2*Pi*(fi - fk + δf)*t], {t, 0, T}] + Ν1
```

It should have been Cos(something) -1 /something.

Answer in INTEGRAL SOLVER is good

[image]

Comment: What is the Mathematica code that you are running? (Please put it in text so that we can copy/paste it). Integrate[Sin[f t], {t, 0, T}] works fine and gives the kind of answer you expect.

Comment: Directly post your Mathematica code.

Comment: In which formate you need the code? 

(1/2)*\[Alpha] \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(T\)]\(Sin\ [2*\[Pi] \((\*
StyleBox[\(f\*
StyleBox["i",
FontSize->12]\)] - \*
StyleBox[\(f\*
StyleBox["k",
FontSize->12]\)] \*
StyleBox["+",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox["\[Delta]f",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox[" ",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox[")",
FontSize->12]\) \*
StyleBox["t",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox["]",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox[" ",
FontSize->12]\[DifferentialD]t\)\)  + \[CapitalNu]1 @bills

Comment: Edit your original question and add this code :)

Comment: @cvgmt I did :)

Comment: Note `Sin[u]^2` is `Cos[something]`, namely `1/2 (1 - Cos[2 u])`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I did, Please check again

Comment: @MichaelE2 Take this 
(1/2)*\[Alpha] \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(T\)]\(Sin\ [2*\[Pi] \((\*
StyleBox[\(f\*
StyleBox["i",
FontSize->12]\)] - \*
StyleBox[\(f\*
StyleBox["k",
FontSize->12]\)] \*
StyleBox["+",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox["\[Delta]f",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox[" ",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox[")",
FontSize->12]\) \*
StyleBox["t",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox["]",
FontSize->12]\*
StyleBox[" ",
FontSize->12]\[DifferentialD]t\)\)  + \[CapitalNu]1

Comment: It looks correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UeAZ.png

Comment: Simpler case: `Integrate[Sin[2*df*t], {t, 0, T}]`

Comment: Or just `Integrate[Sin[2*t], {t, 0, T}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thankyou for your help, Actually I am an amateur /dabbler?dilettante in Mathematica rn, Code converted to Raw form is this 

(1/2)*\[Alpha]*Integrate[Sin[2*Pi*(fi - fk + \[Delta]f)*t], {t, 0, T}] + 
  \[CapitalNu]1

Comment: @MichaelE2 (1/2)*\[Alpha]*Integrate[Sin[2*Pi*(fi - fk + \[Delta]f)*t], {t, 0, T}] + 
  \[CapitalNu]1 I wish and hope it works

Comment: @MichaelE2 I solved this in https://www.integral-calculator.com 
Code of that is (sin(2*pi(f-k+d)t)  put limits it works perfectly there, In the mathematical answer is different. It has square values in the numerator

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the mathematical answer", but `Sin[u]^2 == 1/2 (1 - Cos[2u]` is an identity that converts one form to the other.  Both answers are correct.  (At least I'm assuming the integral-calculator.com answer is correct.) — Pay attention to the arguments of sine and cosine: one has a factor of two, the other has a squared function but lacks the factor of two.

Comment: @MichaelE2 cos^2 = I -sin^2 
This isn't square here

Comment: I don't want a square here @MichaelE2

Comment: @MichaelE2 In Integral solver, see the picture there is no square, while in Mathematica we have an extra square

Comment: You can get rid of the square with `TrigReduce[answer]`.

Comment: Micheal, YOU MADE MY DAY. GOD BE WITH YOU ...... ALWAYSSSSSSSSSS

Comment: @MichaelE2 WISH I COULD OFFER YOU A COFFE

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr1 = (1/2)*α*
   Integrate[Sin[2*Pi*(fi - fk + δf)*t], {t, 0, T}] + Ν1

(* Ν1 + (α Sin[π T (fi - fk + δf)]^2)/(2 π (fi - fk + δf)) *)
```

If you don't like this form, force a different form using a custom [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

```
expr2 = Simplify[expr1, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 1000 Count[#, _Sin, {0, Infinity}] &)]

(* (α + 4 π (fi - fk + δf) Ν1 - α Cos[
     2 π T (fi - fk + δf)])/(4 π (fi - fk + δf)) *)
```

Or,

```
expr3 = Simplify /@ (expr2 // Apart)

(* α/(4 π (fi - fk + δf)) + Ν1 - (α Cos[
   2 π T (fi - fk + δf)])/(4 π (fi - fk + δf)) *)
```

Verifying that the forms are equivalent

```
expr1 == expr2 == expr3 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Bob, It works the same way. However, the answer should have been 

$ Cos (2*pi(fi-fk+daltaF))-1/4pi(fi+dalF)T

Comment: Bob I edited the question for further help

Comment: It appears that you used `{\[CapitalNu]1 -> 0, \[Alpha] -> 2}`. The results are equivalent forms.

Comment: GOD BE WITH YOU, ALWAYSSSSS, THANK YOU  BOB !!!!!!!